# What is the difference between sum() and count() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, count, sum

Can you help me understand the difference between the statements mentioned below? Given that `Survived` column contains binary data (0,1), they give different answers:

```
df_train[df_train.Sex == 'female'].Survived.count()
df_train[df_train.Sex == 'female'].Survived.sum()
```

Comment: count() gives number of items in a column & sum gives sum of the values in a column

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sum()` is for like `1+0 = 1`. if data is `3` and `3` then it will return `6`.

`count()` return number of rows, so it will return 2.

Answer (score 2):

`count()` will just count number of rows.

`sum()` will sum the 1's and 0's.

Comment: `count()` only counts the number of non missing values, so records with `NaN`s or other missing values are not included in that count.

Answer (score 2):

**`count()`** 
It's a string function, which count the total number of individual category. And that's the reason we put this in quotes while using it in aggregate function.

Ex

```
grouped = order_products_all.groupby("product_id")["reordered"].aggregate(
    {'reorder_sum': sum,'reorder_total': 'count'}
).reset_index()
```

**`sum()`** It's a integer function, which sum the number of unique category.