# How to get parents data that only has a child data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get all the data from the parent that only has a child. Please see my code below.

```
$customers = Customer::with(['items' => function($query){
            return $query->where('status', 2);
        }])->get();

        dd($customers);
```

But the code above returns all the customer. By the way, I'm using laravel 4.2.

Items Table:
[image]

Customer Table:
[image]

Comment: Have you created relationship between both customer and items? and show the customer model code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**with()** is for eager loading. That basically means, along the main model, Laravel will preload the relationship(s) you specify. This is especially helpful if you have a collection of models and you want to load a relation for all of them. Because with eager loading you run only one additional DB query instead of one for every model in the collection.

**has()** is to filter the selecting model based on a relationship. So it acts very similarly to a normal WHERE condition. If you just use has('relation') that means you only want to get the models that have at least one related model in this relation.

e.g :

```
$users = Customer::has('items')->get();
// only Customer that have at least one item are contained in the collection
```

**whereHas()** works basically the same as has() but allows you to specify additional filters for the related model to check.

e.g

```
$users = Customer::whereHas('items', function($q){
    $q->where('status', 2);
})->get();
// only customer that have item status 2
```

Adding group by to calculating sum 
this is another example from my code :

```
Customer::select(['customer.name', DB::raw('sum(sale.amount_to_pay) AS total_amount'), 'customer.id'])
            ->where('customer.store_id', User::storeId())
            ->join('sale', 'sale.customer_id', '=', 'customer.id')
            ->groupBy('customer.id', 'customer.name')
            ->orderBy('total_amount', 'desc')
            ->take($i)
            ->get()
```

in your case :

```
Customer::select(['customer_id', DB::raw('sum(quantity) AS total')])
            ->whereHas('items', function ($q) {
                $q->where('status', 2);
            })
            ->groupBy('customer_id')
            ->get();
```

whereHas() allow you to filter data or query for the related model in your case 
those customer that have items and it status is 2

afetr getting data we are perform `->groupBy('customer_id')`

The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

`select(['customer_id', DB::raw('sum(quantity) AS total')])` this will select customer id and calculate the sum of quantity column

Comment: It is working. One more question. How can I group it by customers, so I can sum up the quantity using `quantity` field each customer.

Comment: can you display table format so i can understand well.

Comment: use groupBY() before get();  e.g : ->groupBY('customer_id')

Comment: Hi Dhruv. May I ask an explanation with the part "in your case"? So I can understand what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, please add the explanation with that part.

Comment: ok i will explain line by line. check answer after some time.

Comment: Wait Dhruv, I got an error: `1054 Unknown column 'quantity' in Customer table`. The quantity is in the `items` table not in `customers`. Sorry about that.

Comment: check new answer

Comment: finally complete :)

Comment: just add your answer so anyone get it

Comment: I apologize; I just got wrong data from my database :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `whereHas` not `with` to check child existence.

```
$customers = Customer::whereHas('items', function($query){
    return $query->where('status', 2);
})->get();

dd($customers);
```

I assume you already defined proper relationship between `Customer` and `Item`.

Comment: It is working. One more question. How can I group it by customers, so I can sum up the quantity using `quantity` field each customer.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
$customers = Customer::whereHas('items', function($query){
     $query->where('status', 2);
})->get();

dd($customers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Customer::select(['items.customer_id',DB::raw('count(items.id) AS total_qty')])
        ->join('items', 'items.user_id', '=', 'customer.customer_id')
        ->groupBy('items.customer_id')
        ->havingRaw('total_qty > 2')
        ->get();
```

OR

```
$data=DB::select("select `items`.`customer_id`, count(items.id) AS total_qty
from `customers`
inner join `items`
on `items`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`customer_id`
group by `items`.`customer_id` having total_qty >= 2");
```

correct table name and column name.

Comment: Can you also add the explanation?

Comment: Why do we have `count()` in DB raw? isn't that sum?

Comment: sum() vs count() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684192/what-is-the-difference-between-sum-and-count-in-pandas/48684278#48684278

Comment: I don't use db-fiddle. I've already include the screenshot of my tables fields.

Comment: but i can't  test query in screenshot :)

Comment: Alright. Try this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eFG6JubsMEwLEmdAuPLuQN/0

Comment: go and check sql query and answer https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jtyanubW32EAUYaizfYEK1/0