# Python - isnull().sum() vs isnull().count()

Tags: python, null, nan, notnull

So I'm currently finishing a tutorial with the titanic dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data).
Now I'm trying a couple of new things that might be related.

The info for it is : 
[image]
There are **891 entries(red asterisk)**, and **columns with NaN values (blue dashes)**.

---

When I went to find a little summary of the missing values I got confused by `.sum()` & `.count()`:

[image]

In the above code, `.sum()` is incrementing by one for each instance of a null value. So it seems that the output is the value of how many missing entries there are for each column in the data frame. (which is what I want)

---

**However** if we do `.count()` we get 891 for each column no matter if we use `.isnull().count()` or `.notnull().count()`.

[image]

So my question(s) is :

**What does `.count()` mean in this context?**

I thought that it would count every instance of the wanted method (in this case every instance of a null or not null entry; basically what `.sum()` did).

**Also; my "definition" of how `.sum()` is being used, is that correct?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684192/what-is-the-difference-between-sum-and-count-in-pandas

Answer (score 2):

Just print out the data of train_df.isnull(), you will see it.

```
# data analysis and wrangling
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# visualization
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

train_df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
print(train_df.isnull())
```

result:

```
    PassengerId  Survived  Pclass   Name    Sex    Age  SibSp  Parch  Ticket  \
    0          False     False   False  False  False  False  False  False   False   
    1          False     False   False  False  False  False  False  False   False   
    2          False     False   False  False  False  False  False  False   False   
    3          False     False   False  False  False  False  False  False   False   
    4          False     False   False  False  False  False  False  False   False   
    ..           ...       ...     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...     ...   
    886        False     False   False  False  False  False  False  False   False   
    887        False     False   False  False  False  False  False  False   False   
    888        False     False   False  False  False   True  False  False   False   
    889        False     False   False  False  False  False  False  False   False   
    890        False     False   False  False  False  False  False  False   False
```

**It got 891 rows, full of Trues and False.**

1. When you use **sum()**, it will return the sum of every column, which adds trues(=1) and false(= 0) together.Like this

```
print(False+False+True+True)
```

```
    2
```

2. When you use **count()**, it just returns **the number of rows**.

Of course, you will get 891 for each column no matter you use .isnull().count() or .notnull().count().

Answer (score 2):

`data.isnull().count()` returns the total number of rows irrespective of missing values.  You need to use `data.isnull().sum()`.