# Pandas DataFrame All Values Missing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isnull

I am using a dataset of 962 rows with 0 missing values, but when I run isnull() on it, I get as a result that the whole dataset is empty.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot

ts = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")

df = pd.DataFrame(ts)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print(df.isnull().count())
```

Output on the kernel:

```
date           962
tmax (degC)    962
tmin (degC)    962
af (days)      962
rain (mm)      962
sun (hrs)      962
dtype: int64
```

Any clue what is happening here?

Comment: Will you please show a sample of the dataframe after you read it? `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `count` to `sum`, count will return not `NaN` value number total, in your case you need count the number of `NaN`, so we do `sum`

```
print(df.isnull().sum())
```

Comment: Nice catch! Do you think this should be closed as a typo question?

Comment: Feel free to do that so @richardec

Comment: Actually @BENY I found a post that can be used a good dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60249807/17242583 - will you please close this Q as a dupe of that? I alread VTC'd for typo so I can't...